# Am I using in "which in turn" correctly?

Tags: clauses

The windows do not block out sun light which in turn causes problems such as glares, eye damage, and skin damage for students.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are.  The idiom has two meanings.  You are using the first of those given below.  You could replace "which in turn" with "and so" or "and because of that" and the meaning would be the same.

> **in turn**
>
> 1) because of that:
>   *Stress ​causes ​your ​body to ​release ​chemicals, which in turn ​boost ​blood ​pressure.*
>
> 2) one after the other, in ​order:
>   *She ​spoke to each of the ​guests in turn.*
>
> [cambridge.org](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/in-turn)

Comment: Note that "which in turn" cannot simply be replaced by "and so" or "and because of that" in the OPs sentence.  "Which" is a relative pronoun for sunlight; you'd have to write something like "..., and so this sunlight then" to fully capture the meaning.